# Unable to delete an app which installed by twrp

Tags: recovery-mode

I faced this problem when i delete one app and installed again by twrp in the recovery mode.
When i delete this app afterwords and restart the system it will appear again
I tried many times to delete but every time is coming back after restart

Comment: Which app? How did you install it via TWRP, from a zip file?